# Osmdroid 6.0.1 with Mapsforge: invalid resource

Tags: android, osmdroid, mapsforge

We were using osmdroid in our Android app together with Mapsforge for offline maps for some time now. This week we decided to update to version 6.0.1. Since then I receive the following errors when I try to display a map which is using osmdroid:

```
E/XmlUtils: invalid resource: symbols/transport/helicopter_pad.svg
E/XmlUtils: invalid resource: symbols/transport/airport.svg
E/XmlUtils: invalid resource: symbols/poi/cave.svg
            invalid resource: symbols/volcano.svg
E/XmlUtils: invalid resource: symbols/peak1.svg
            invalid resource: symbols/poi/mountain_pass.svg
            invalid resource: symbols/poi/mountain_pass.svg
E/XmlUtils: invalid resource: symbols/health/hospital.svg
            invalid resource: symbols/health/pharmacy.svg
            invalid resource: symbols/health/doctors.svg
E/XmlUtils: invalid resource: symbols/poi/embassy2.svg
            invalid resource: symbols/accommodation/shelter2.svg
            invalid resource: symbols/accommodation/alpinehut.svg
E/XmlUtils: invalid resource: symbols/accommodation/camping.svg
[... more similar errors ]
```

The map is still displayed but I think the symbols above are missing and no longer shown.

**What we did in detail**

we updated our libraries from

```
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.5'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:5.6.5'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.6.1'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:0.6.1'
```

to:

```
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.1'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.0.1'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.8.0'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:0.8.0'
```

I also tested with osmdroid 6.0.1 and the original Mapsforge libraries 0.6.1, with the same result. Unfortunately I am not the developer which originally integrated the libraries to our Android project. Therefore I'm not sure if I need to add these resources manually somehow? Maybe someone else encountered this problem too?

Not sure if this information is of any help, but I was testing the app on Android 6 and 8.

Comment: hi, i'm facing the same issue. but in my case I cannot see the offline map. can you helpme?

Answer (score 0):

When updgrading

- from org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.1 with org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:0.6.1
- to org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.0 with org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:0.11.0

i had to add to make it work-

- 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-themes:0.11.0'

i am now using

```
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.0'
implementation ('org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.1.0')
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.11.0'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:0.11.0'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-themes:0.11.0'
```

Maybe the missing .svg files have moved to a different package?